# Android Annotations @AfterViews called 3 times

Tags: android, android-annotations

I'm using Android Annotations and my method annotated with @AfterViews is called 3 times. I debugged the generated class and i figure that these 3 methods are invoked but i dont know why.

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    afterSetContentView_();
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view, LayoutParams params) {
    super.setContentView(view, params);
    afterSetContentView_();
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    super.setContentView(view);
    afterSetContentView_();
}
```

-- edit 1 --
My activity declaration is the only place where I set a layout:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.real_estate_customer_leads_list)
public class RealEstateCustomerLeadsListActivity extends
    SlidingFragmentActivity implements FilterResponseHandler {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's probably because one super is calling the other. Something like this:

```
 // super.setContentView(layoutResID); code is:
 View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(layoutResId);
 setContentView(v);

// then super.setContentView(view); code is:
setContentView(view, null);

// then super.setContentView(view, params);
this one now actually do real work. Hence, 3 calls!
```

Comment: They are not chained. I tested in one Activity that correctly calls @AfterViews method once. Only the first one public void setContentView(int layoutResID) is called.

Comment: that answer was a 'best guess'. Sorry! Good luck!